# Steep of the proof of embedding $\mathbb{RP}^{2}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, matrix-rank

Hi i would like some help to prove that the application $F:\mathbb{S}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{4}$, where $F(x,y,z)=(x^{2}-y^{2},xy,xz,yz)$ is an immersion. I noted that $F=\bar{F}\circ i$, where $i:\mathbb{S}^{2}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ is an embeddeding,in particular, an immersion and $\bar{F}:\mathbb{R}^{3}\to \mathbb{R}^{4}$ with $\bar{F}(x,y,z)=(x^{2}-y^{2},xy,xz,yz)$. Therefore for the prove that $F$ is an immersion simply show that $\bar{F}$ is an immersion, but $\bar{F}$ has two minors with determinants $2x(x^{2}+y^{2})$ and $2y(x^{2}+y^{2})$ , thus $\bar{F}$ has rank $3$ except when $x=y=0$. I don't know continue, any tips?

Comment: You're right that $\overline{F}$ is not an immersion, but this doesn't mean that $F$ can't be an immersion.  For a stupid example, consider $\mathbb{R}\xrightarrow{i} \mathbb{R}^3\xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{R}^2$ where $i$ is the natural inclusion onto the first cooridinate an $\pi$ projects onto the first to coordinates.  Then $\pi$ is not an immersion, but the composition is just the inclusion $\mathbb{R}\xrightarrow{i}\mathbb{R}^2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, so is an immersion.

Comment: Hi @JasonDeVito , there exists another way to prove that $F$ is an immersion?

Comment: You can use charts on $S^2$.  Alternatively, note that $d\overline{F}$ has rank $2$ unless $x=y=z=0$, which is impossible on $S^2$.